# Count of all rows in all DataTables in a DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I'm using .Net and would like to count all the Rows in all the DataTables in a Dataset. I'd expected something like this to work

```
int totalRows = myDataSet.SelectMany(dt => dt.rows().count).Sum()
```

or

```
int totalRows = myDataSet.AsEnumrable().SelectMany(dt => dt.rows().count).Sum();
```

But neither of those is close to working and google has drawn a blank

Comment: _But neither of those is close to working _ - How you know they aren't working? Did you get an exception?

Comment: @Fabio doesn't even compile and I think that's due to IEnumerable being needed somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Linq to Query the Tables. For example,

```
var rows = dataSet.Tables
                  .Cast<DataTable>()
                  .Sum(x => x.Rows.Count);
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m0STGp)